# Kotlin Unsigned Bytes with javascript Uint8ClampedArray

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js-interop

I have a program which is trying to set values in ImageData represented as a [Uint8ClampedArray](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/org.khronos.webgl/-uint8-clamped-array/index.html) in a Kotlin program. According to [the specification for the set method](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/org.khronos.webgl/set.html), I need to pass a Kotlin byte into the array, but Kotlin bytes are signed:

```
    ...create context...
    //setup pix as a js Uint8ClampedArray
    val imgd = context.createImageData(100.0, 100.0)
    val pix = imgd.data   //pix is now a Uint8ClampedArray

    //sets pix[40] to 127
    pix[40] = 127
    //gives an error - Kotlin bytes are signed, so it cannot be passed as a literal
    pix[40] = 200
    //also doesn't work, still converts to a signed byte
    pix[40] = 200.toByte()
```

My problem with this is that Javascript will read this as only 127, not 255. How can I set values of this array to be greater than 127? I can't even find a hack-y way to make the JS result read what I want, because ultimately the assignment needs a signed byte which doesn't allow for values greater than 127.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out! You can do an unsafe cast of the UInt8 array to a UInt16 array, then use that instead, and javascript seems to figure out what you mean:

```
    //instead of val pix = imgd.data
    val pix = imgd.data.unsafeCast<Uint16Array>()
    // now you can assign values outside the -127..127 range
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue in the Kotlin tracker — https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24583

> org.khronos.webgl.Uint8ClampedArray getter and setter declarations use Byte. Which means assigning values over 127 to it is not trivial.
>   Also the values obtained from it violate the Byte contract
>
> Besides one could argue that it is not a "real" array. Assigning values outside of 0..255 range is completely normal for it.
>
> This case is important, because it is used for the canvas manipulation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/data